# Downloading folders from inside a zip file

Tags: devops, artifactory, jfrog-cli

Is there a way to download folders from inside a zip file using JFrog CLI?

On one hand, one can browse into zip files so that it appears like normal folders.

But, downloading a folder from within a zip file is not possible, while it is possible to download a single file from within the zip file.

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported by the JFrog CLI at the moment. What you can do is:

1. [Download](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-DownloadingFiles) the whole artifacts from the archive in a single command using the CLI, with the `jfrog rt dl` command while passing `--explode=true` flag. This will download the zip file and extract it.
2. Download a single file from the zip file, using the [Archive Entry Download](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArchiveEntryDownload) Rest API. For convience, you run the request with JFrog CLI, using the [Running cUrl](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-RunningcUrl) command.